# Try ... except в TeleramBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
try:
    global minProtein 
    minProtein = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text = 'The max amount of protein in the recipe: ', parse_mode = "html")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_maxProtein)
except Exception as e:
    bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')
```

Есть такой вот кусок кода. Никак не могу разобраться как работает "except Exception as e:". Какую функцию выполняет.

Comment: Значит что отловит любые возникшие ошибки в коде от try до except. И вместо того чтобы она вывалилась как сама ошибка в приложении, отправит в телеграм сообщение `oooops`. И вы поймете что что-то пошло не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой строке мы перехватываем исключение (условно - ошибку), и вместо того чтобы вылететь программа выполнит код, находящийся после блока except

Подробнее здесь: https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/570882/

Comment: а почему именно except Exception as e, а не просто except Exception. Что дает это "as e'?

Comment: Было бы полезнее прочитать статью, там об этом есть, но если нужно кратко, то except Exception as e говорит о том, что исключение будет записано в переменную e, если сделать print(e) в блоке except - сможешь прочитать суть ошибки